# Update DIV that contains php-generated <ul> code when new inputs submitted

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fancybox-3

EDIT: I did some code inspection of some nested include files in the child PHP file and discovered some conflicts with the parent PHP include files. The impact is that the child PHP file/calling div has dependencies on the parent being refreshed so I can't refresh the specific div without a full page refresh. I have some PHP restructuring/decoupling work to do before I can get this working so please don't invest effort on this question until I come back when that work is complete. Cheers.

EDIT 2: I found the problem.  Some js I was using was not re-executable at runtime so the associated DIV would not rebuild. The stuff I had written using .load() was working ok.  I moved the implementation from a reloadable DIV to an iframe solution until I can fix the js issue. Cheers.

---

Here's the context:

- javascript grid constructed from html ul
- ul for grid generated using php looping through mySQL database
- SO FAR, SO GOOD, ALL THIS WORKS GREAT WHEN PAGE LOADS
- now user SUCCESSFULLY enters another entry in mySQL database using fancybox UI
- fancybox UI collapses upon success, but grid needs to be refreshed to reflect the new entry.
- Fancybox AFTERCLOSE can be used to reload the parent page just fine, which updates the grid, but it reloads the whole page which sucks.
- I have not been able to figure out a way to get the php database extraction file to re-run after the new user entry, which would update the array built from the mySQL database, which is used by php code to generate the ul for the grid.
- Main executable = index.php / Grid executable (included) = grid.php / PHP database extraction = profilesettings.php
- How do I get the PHP settings file to re-run to rebuild the array from the mySQL database after a new entry, then how do I reload the div to rebuild the js grid so I don't have to reload the whole page?

Fancybox attachment & settings:

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
toolbar  : false,
smallBtn : true,
afterClose: function () {parent.location.reload(true);}
```

HTML markup:

```
<div id="ytgrid">
   <?php include("grid.php"); ?>
</div>
```

grid.php code to build the grid:

```
    <ul data-category-name="Main">

            <!--==============================================================>
            <     PHP populate grid from database                       >
            <===============================================================-->

            <?php

            for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($LinkCol1);$i++){

                echo "$LinkCol1[$i]";
                echo "<li data-url='$LinkCol1[$i]'
                        data-width='900' data-height='506'
                        data-extra-button-url='https://www.webdesign-flash.ro'
                        data-extra-button-target='_blank'><img src='$LinkCol2[$i]' alt='$user_name on x10host.com/' />
                        <div data-thumbnail-content1=''>
                            <div class='extraContent1'
                                style='font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;'>$youtubeLinkCol3[$i]</div>
                                </div>
                        </li>";

            }

            ?>

     </ul>
```

I believe the issue is figuring out how to reload the php settings file, which will populate the array variables with the latest database entries, and then to refresh the ytgrid DIV to rebuild the grid including any new entries.

A lot of things are in motion here. I hope you can help. Please fire away with questions.  Thx.

Comment: Either update your grid manually (using ajax) or use some js framework to "connect" your view with server side.

Comment: @Janis - yes, of course.  I'm posting here because I haven't yet been able to get ajax working for what I need.  It isn't just a variable update, the PHP script has to re-run/load to generate the html ul code for the new entries as though it were a new page load.  If you have any specific suggestions, I'd welcome them.  Same about being more specific on "some js framework to "connect" your view with server side" ...for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having with loading a DIV dynamically was due to some js s/w that required a full pageload and would not re-execute at runtime.  I need to get that fixed but it is unrelated to this question, which is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If user entry new information on this page, you can set callback on entre new information and  there get new data with ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax-listener.php",
  cache: false
})
.done(function( html ) {
    $( "#results" ).html( html );
});
```

Before it you should create ajax end point(php file), which will be send request to your database.

Comment: This is interesting. I've tried Ajax a number of different ways but I may have been using it in the wrong place.  I know when to send the request to the database – on close of the fancybox window – and I know whether or not the database has been updated so I know whether or not the grid needs to be refreshed.  I just haven't been able to get the PHP to get the updated data and reload the grid. I'll try this in the next couple of days.  Thx.